# ANTLR: loop did not match anything at input

Tags: eclipse, antlr

sorry for my english! I have problem, faced here with such a problem, give the decision:

> line 1:0 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input < E O F
>   >

This my file, calc.g

```
grammar calc;

options {
  language = Java;
}

rule: statement+;


statement
    : expr NEWLINE
    | ID '=' expr NEWLINE
    | NEWLINE
    ;

NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n'
    ;

expr
    : multExpression ('+' multExpression |'-' multExpression)*
    ; 

multExpression
    : a1=atom ('*' a2=atom | '/' a2=atom)*
    ;

atom
    : ID
    | INT 
    | '(' expr ')' 
    ;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

INT :   ('1'..'9') ('0'..'9')*
    ;
```

this is my main:

```
ANTLRReaderStream input = new ANTLRReaderStream(); 
calcLexer lexer = new calcLexer(input); 
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer); 
calcParser parser = new calcParser(tokens); 
parser.rule();
```

Comment: this is my main:
ANTLRReaderStream input = new ANTLRReaderStream();
calcLexer lexer = new calcLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
calcParser parser = new calcParser(tokens);
parser.rule();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your input is empty: the parser immediately encounters the `EOF` (end-of-file) where it expects at least one `statement`.

Try something like this:

```
ANTLRStringStream input = new ANTLRStringStream("2*42\n"); 
calcLexer lexer = new calcLexer(input); 
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer); 
calcParser parser = new calcParser(tokens); 
parser.rule();
```

As 280Z28 mentioned in the comment beneath my answer, you should probably force the parser to consume the entire input by adding `EOF` at the end of your parser's entry point:

```
rule: statement+ EOF;
```

and if you want to allow an empty string to be valid input too, change the `+` to a `*`;

```
rule: statement* EOF;
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test it but think you have to add the default EOF token to your grammar:

```
rule: statement+ EOF!;
```

Your parser seems to recognize the whole input but at the end there is an EOF but you did not add the corresponding rule to your grammar.

Comment: No, that is not necessary, although good practice. The error is about the parser expecting a `statement` but finding the `EOF` instead. Also, you added the `!` operator, which is invalid without the `output=AST;` in the `options{...}`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had that problem in a project with ANTLR 3.3/3.4 and solved it by the help of that token. Which version of ANTLR is used?

Comment: The OP is using ANTLR 3.